# tcl string replace ip address 10.1.1.1 to 10.1.1.0

Tags: tcl

Hi all I have a variable which is an ip address of 10.1.1.1 I want to replace the last octet in the string to b 0

I have tried a few things from string replace and regsub but I have not really got anything that worked for me. can someone suggest how to change a string of 10.1.1.1 to 10.1.1.0 ?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Also have a look at the Tcllib ip package for general manipulation of IP adresses. (http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/tcllib_ip.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you try? `regsub` can do this pretty trivially.

```
regsub {\d+$} $input 0
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I was trying to make it more complicated then it needed to be.

Comment: expect31.76> regsub {\d+$} $tgen1(rtr1.edge,traffic_dst_ip) 0
10.1.1.0

Answer (score 2):

```
% set ip 10.1.1.1
10.1.1.1
% set new [join [lreplace [split $ip .] end end 0] .]
10.1.1.0
```